# use insert_id with two insert db table at the same time (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

i need your help.
I want to use insert_id with two insert data table at the same time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLw0X.jpg)

---

```
function add_donhang(){
        $this->db->insert('donhang', array(
            'tendonhang' => $this->input->post('txttendonhang'),
            'madonhang' => $this->input->post('txtmadonhang'),
            'idkhachhang' => $this->input->post('idkhachhang'),
        )); // after insert table "donhang" and at the same time insert into "phieuxuatkho"
        $this->db->insert('phieuxuatkho', array(
            'tendonhang' => $this->input->post('txttendonhang'),
        ));
        $id = $this->db->insert_id(); // Get id of "donhang".
        $id2 = $this->db->insert_id(); // Get if of "phieuxuatkho". 
        if ($id) {
            $dulieusp = array();
            $dsmasp = $this->input->post('masp');
            $dstensp = $this->input->post('tensp');
            $dsslsp = $this->input->post('soluong');
            $dsmsp = $this->input->post('midsp');
            foreach ($dsmasp as $key => $item) {
                $dulieusp[] = array(
                    'masanpham' => $item,
                    'tensanpham' => $dstensp[$key],
                    'madonhang' => $id, //id of "donhang".
                    'maphieuxuat' => $id2, //if of "phieuxuatkho". 
                    'idsanpham' => $dsmsp[$key],
                    'soluong' => $dsslsp[$key],
                );
            }
            if (count($dulieusp)) {
                $this->db->insert_batch('chitietdonhang', $dulieusp);
            }
            return array(
                'type' => 'successful',
                'message' => ' Thêm Đơn Hàng Thành Công'
            );
        } else {
            return array(
                'type' => 'error',
                'message' => ' Không Có Đơn Hàng Thêm Vào'
            );
        }
    }
```

---

how can i do it with the simple way. Thanks for help me

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please copy the text of the function from your image into the Question and format it as a code segment.  If you are not sure how much of the function to copy over just copy all of the function.  Copying text to the question rather than using an image of the text is better because it makes it easier to  copy a segment of code and use it in an Answer.  Also, the link will break if its host ever stops hosting it.

Comment: why are you not using model in codeigniter. This is bad code if you are using `Codeigniter`. If you want `insert_id` then just write `$id = $this->db->insert_id(); ` below first insert query.